# Update parent field if status in its related list are all updated

Tags: trigger, update

I have a field status on my parent object.
If the status in its child  is updated, the parent status is updated accordingly.
Ex: 
if one of the childStatus == 'sad', parentStatus = 'sad'
if one of the childStatus == 'cry', parentStatus = 'cry'
if all childStatus == 'happy', parentStatus = 'happy'.

I'm new to salesforce, please help.

Here's my sample code so far.

```
public static String updatejobApplicationStatus(Set<Id> offerIdSet){
        if(offerIdSet != null || offerIdSet.size()> 0){
            set<id> jobApplicationIdSet = new set <id>();
            String status = '';

        //----------------using offer id, get the application id of those offer id---------------   
        list<Offer__c> offersList = [Select Id,Job_Application__c FROM Offer__c WHERE id in:offerIdSet];
        for(Offer__c jobAppId: offersList){
            jobApplicationIdSet.add(jobAppId.Job_Application__c);                
        }
        //------------------- get the status of these offers------------------------             
        list<Offer__c> offersUpdateList = [Select Id,Job_Application__c,Status__c FROM Offer__c WHERE Job_Application__c in:jobApplicationIdSet];
        system.debug('----------------offersUpdateList---------'+ offersUpdateList); 
        map<id, string> jobMapOffer = new map<id, string>();    
        map<id, list<string>> mapList= new map<id, list<string>>();
        list<String> offerStatusList = new list<String>();

        Set<Job_Application__c> jobAppUpdate = new Set<Job_Application__c>();

            for(Offer__c off : offersUpdateList){

              if(off.Status__c == 'Part Time'){                     
                    Job_Application__c newJob = new Job_Application__c(Status__c = off.Status__c ,Id = off.Job_Application__c);
                    jobAppUpdate.add(newJob);
                    break;  
                }                                     

                else if(off.Status__c == 'Night'){                      
                    Job_Application__c newJob = new Job_Application__c(Status__c = off.Status__c,Id = off.Job_Application__c);
                    jobAppUpdate.add(newJob);
                    break;

                }
                else if(off.Status__c == 'Day'){                

                    Job_Application__c newJob = new Job_Application__c(Status__c =off.Status__c ,Id = off.Job_Application__c);
                    jobAppUpdate.add(newJob);

                }
                else{                       
                    Job_Application__c newJob = new Job_Application__c(Status__c = 'Full day' ,Id = off.Job_Application__c);
                    jobAppUpdate.add(newJob);
                    break; 

                }


            }
             List<Job_Application__c> jobList = New List<Job_Application__c>(jobAppUpdate);
             update jobList;            
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is the relationship of Offer__c and Job_Application__c master-detail or lookup?  And do you have flexibility to change fields, such as changing Job_Application__c.Status__c from text to formula?

Comment: You can refer @animesh answer. I believe it might work.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one. It is made on Contact which is child and account as its parent.

```
trigger UpdateChildRecord on Contact(after update) {

 Set <ID> parentSet = new Set <ID>();
 for(Contact c : Trigger.new)
 {
  parentSet.add(c.AccountId);
 }

 List <Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Parent_Status__c, (SELECT Id, Child_Status__c FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN : parentSet];

 for(Account a : accList)
  {
   integer count=0;
   for(Contact c : a.Contacts)
   {
    if(c.Child_Status__c == 'Cry')
    {
     a.Parent_Status__c = 'Cry';
    }
    else if(c.Child_Status__c == 'Sad')
    {
     a.Parent_Status__c = 'Sad';
    }
    else if(c.Child_Status__c == 'Happy')
    {
     count++;
     //a.Parent_Status__c = 'Happy';
    }   
   }  
   if(a.contacts.size()==count){
       a.Parent_Status__c = 'Happy';
   }

  }
  update accList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to try something. We cant provide the whole code here. I can provide you the logic though,

Write a trigger on Child object after insert and using inner query for parent to update its status.

You can learn writing trigger here,
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm